# combinations problem.

Tags: combinatorics

If you have 5 women and 7 men, and you are after how many different groups of 2 women and 3 men you can form then i understand that the answer is:

${5\choose2} * {7\choose3}$ = 350 groups

but what if you are told that 2 men can't be grouped together then you have to look at the 35 possible groups of 3 from 7 and take away:

${2\choose2}*{5\choose1}$ = 5 groups

then proceed as before. But where did this calculation come from i dont understand it?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Carlos.The number of ways that A,B, men, are together, you can chose the third man in 5 ways, or $\binom{5}{1}$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the men are $M_1,\cdots, M_7$ and that it's $M_1,M_2$ that can't be sat together.

We already have the unrestricted total so we just want to subtract off the ones that have $M_1,M_2$ together.

If a group contains $M_1,M_2$ then there are $5$ men remaining from which to choose the third man.  That the $\binom 51$ term.

There are no new rules on the women, so we still have $\binom 52$ ways to choose the women on the group.

Thus there are $$\binom 51\times \binom 52$$ groups of $3$ men and $2$ women which contain both $M_1$ and $M_2$.  So the number of groups of $3$ men and $2$ women which do not contain both $M_1$ and $M_2$ is $$\binom 73\times \binom 52-\binom 51\times \binom 52=\binom 52\times \left(\binom 73-\binom 51\right)$$

Note: I'm not entirely sure how this connects to the answer you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If the two distinguished men stand together, then there are obviously $5$ ways to choose the remaining man in the group.  The calculation $${2\choose2}{5\choose1}$$ is attempting to generalize this argument somehow, but I don't really think it succeeds.  Yes, if we were told that there were to be $4$ men in a group then the second factor would be ${5\choose2}$, so that's okay.

It's hard for me to see what the first factor is supposed to generalize to. 
If we were told that there were $3$ men, no two of whom would stand together, then we could say that there are ${3\choose2}$ ways to choose two men would can't stand together, but we'd have to have to worry about the double-counting the cases where all three are in the final group.